# Pull Dates From SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, echo

I am having trouble pull dates within a user selected range from a MSSQL database. I assume the problem has something to do with the comparison in my select statement because I think sql gives dates a special format, so I am having trouble comparing my string sql variable against the date variables in the sql database. First I will show you my code php code and then a screenshot of a date. Thank you for your help and assistance it is appreciated.

I am printing out the array that should be populated with the dates so that I see if it's working. Also dates are pulled from the user as mm/dd/yyyy. My echo statement prints out 31 when I search between the dates of 02/03/2014 and 02/18/2014.

```
//testing ranges
$testArray = array();
$startDate = $_POST['datepicker'];
$endDate = $_POST['datepicker2'];
$startDate = explode("/", $startDate);
$endDate = explode("/",$endDate);
$startDate = $startDate[2]."-".$startDate[0]."-".$startDate[1]." "."00:00:00.000";
$endDate = $endDate[2]."-".$endDate[0]."-".$endDate[1]." "."00:00:00.000";

$ifTest = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS testD FROM dbo.Response WHERE dbo.Response.response_date BETWEEN 
'".$startDate."' AND '".$endDate."'";
$db -> query($ifTest);
$x = $db->fetch();
$testArray[] = array('testDate' => $x['testD']);
foreach($testArray as $such)
{
    echo $such['testDate'];
}
//end ranges
```

[image: SQL database]

Comment: Are you aware that your code has a massive sql injection vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

Add a group by clause in your select:

```
ifTest = "SELECT dbo.Response.response_date AS testD FROM dbo.Response WHERE dbo.Response.response_date BETWEEN 
'".$startDate."' AND '".$endDate."' GROUP BY dbo.Response.response_date";
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Thiago so I tried your suggestion and I got 2, when trying between the dates of the 2014-02-03 and 2014-02-20. The answer should be 4.

Comment: So you don't need the use of COUNT(*), just modify the query to return the response_date, I'll edit the query

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, everything is actually working correctly. Please ignore this question.